# How to return to previous page with fresh data?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, navigation, reverse

ok So here is my dilemma.. I have :

Views

1)ChildrenListPage
2)NewChildPage

ViewModels:

3) ChildrenListPageViewModel  (Contains a List  Children)

4) NewChildPageViewModel (Contains a Child Kid)

in NewChildPage I collect info for the new child
and navigate back to ChildrenListPage.

What I need is to have the new Child added to the ChildrenList once I return to my ChildrenListPage

Comment: please mention what you tried and where you are getting an error . also please do format your question

Comment: I edited the original question

Answer (score 0):

Override OnAppearing of the view and refresh the data from there.

```
public override void OnAppearing()
{
    //Refresh data
}
```